# Are NSURLSessionDataTask completion blocks called on the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have been trying to figure out when it's okay to "just type in what I need done" and when I need to be specific about what kind of work I am doing on what kind of thread.

As I understand I should only update the UI on my main thread. Does this mean that it's not okay to do something like this? Should I put this into a GDC call?

```
[sessionManager dataTaskWithRequest:aRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    someUILabel.text = @"Hello!"; // Updating my UI
    [someTableView reloadData]; // Ask a table view to reload data

}];
```

That's it for the UI part. Now, let's assume I had an `NSMutableArray` somewhere in in my class. I would be adding or removing objects to this array by for instance tapping a `UIButton`. Then again I have a `NSURLSessionDataTask` going to a server somewhere to get some data and load it into my `NSMutableArray`, like so:

```
[sessionManager dataTaskWithRequest:aRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    myMutableArray = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"results"] mutableCopy];

}];
```

This is not a UI operation. Does this need to be wrapped in a GDC call to avoid crashing in a race condition between my button-tap adding an object (i.e. `[myMutableArray insertObject:someObj atIndex:4];`) while the completion block runs, or are these designed to not clash into each other?

I have left out all error handling to focus on the question at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: It costs you nothing to call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` inside your completion handler, so just do it.

**Long Answer**:

Let's look at the documentation, shall we?

> `completionHandler` The completion handler to call when the load request is complete. This handler is executed on the delegate queue.

The delegate queue is the queue you passed in when you created the NSURLSession with `sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:`. If that's not how you created this NSURLSession, then I suggest you *make no assumptions* about what queue the completion handler is called on. If you didn't pass `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` as this parameter, you are on a background queue and you should break out to the main queue before doing anything that is not thread-safe.

So now the question is:

- Is it thread-safe to update the UI and talk to the table view? No, you must do those things only on the main queue.
- Is it thread-safe to set `myMutableArray`? No, because you would then be sharing a property, `self.myMutableArray`, between two threads (the main queue, where you usually talk to this property, and *this* queue, whatever it is).

Comment: "so just do it": I could, of course, but then I'd be inserting dispatches in all kinds of places without being sure if it was actually necessary or even made sense. I'm well aware this was a solution to the problem at hand, but I am/was trying to understand the problem. But thank you for your explanation. I had a look at the documentation in an attempt to educate myself further. I am using AFNetworking though, and it seems that this by default runs completionBlocks on the main thread, unless specified otherwise, so I don't need to do anything, I guess. You could not know that ofc.

Comment: Sure, fair enough. I hope between us we've ironed out the two aspects of the issue, i.e. what thread is this, and are these moves thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just to make sure I have not misunderstood anything: Assuming AFNetworking does run completionBlocks on the main thread, then it *is* okay to directly access the property (myMutableArray) in that block, since it is then being accessed by the same thread responding to the hypothetical UIButton event that would modify the array at the same time? In other words; it would not be at the same time.

Comment: Absolutely. The main thread is just that: a single thread. And it is strictly sequential. Code from one of these completion handlers can't even _begin_ to run until all of your _other_ code has finished, and vice versa. There is no danger whatever of two things happening "at the same time".

Comment: That's how I had understood it as well. Good. Thank you very much!

Comment: You might enjoy this section of my online book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html#_the_main_thread